# Code for GIF that changes when it hits an edge to bounce around screen DVD-style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for help with some code that I didn't write but am attempting to change for a html file that opens up that we use every now and then.

Is the code we currently have, which grabs gifs from a folder and chooses a random one to pop up in the background, and another random one which used to scroll left to right or top to bottom then change. Unfortunately the keyframes were messed with so I don't have the original keyframes that did that.

However, I am trying to make the gifs bounce around the screen DVD-style, with the gif changing when it hits a side of the screen and am woefully unskilled in coding to make it happen. I would also like the background gif that doesn't move to change every minute. Thanks for the help!

I tried to keyframes I found via googling but obviously they don't work.

See above. I tried the above code and changed the keyframes but it didn't work. I'm not sure what exactly needs to be done to fix this issue as I think there are multiple problems with the code and what I need to do with it. If there is a better place to find answers, please let me know. Thanks.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var path = "images/",
    cycle = 0,
    images = [
      "wheel.png",
      "cathop.gif",
      "catlick.gif",
      "catvibe.gif",
      "catguitar.gif",
      "catcoffee.gif",
      "friends.gif",
      "petfood.gif",
      "catfall.gif",
      "cokementos.gif",
      "cody-rhodes.gif",
      "pumped.gif",
      "brother.gif",
      "giphy.gif",
      "turtle.gif",
      "music.gif",
      "woo.gif",
      "wwe-fail.gif",
      "twirl.gif",
      "strut.gif",
      "bloodsport.gif",
      "vintage.gif",
      "cena.gif",
      "gun-through-the-phone.gif",
      "ill-be-back.gif",
      "van-god-damme.gif",
      "temilator.gif",
      "leonidas.gif",
      "iceman-volleyball.gif",
      "arnnie-commando.webp",
      "bonnie-kids.gif",
      "bollywood-indian.gif",
      "tv-merlin.gif",
      "throw-a-bear-hulk.gif",
      "mars-attacks.gif",
      "chuck-norris.gif",
      "youre-fired.gif",
      "jackman-splosion.gif",
      "the-revenant-leonardo-di-caprio.gif",
      "mask-the-mask.gif",
      "tom-cruise-classified.webp",
      "f14-takeoff.gif",
      "me-after-lockdown-airplane.gif",
      "Aw_HMO.gif",
      "speed-run.gif",
      "boomer-will-live.gif",
      "welcome-to-earth.gif",
      "kick-dropkick.gif",
      "predator-handshake.gif",
      "the-navy.gif",
      "bomb.gif",
      "good-landing.gif",
      "battleship-fire.gif",
      "batman-surfing-gif.gif",
      "dog-wick.gif",
      "surf-this-place.gif",
      "thats-the-spirit.gif",
      "go-ahead-make-my-day-clint-eastwood.gif",
      "face-off-off.gif",
      "pacific-rim-elbow-rocket.gif",
      "t1000.gif",
      "indiana-jones-gun.gif",
      "chuck-norris-bear.gif",
      "happy-silly-gif.gif",
      "washing-dog-silly-animation.gif",
      "sad-keanu.gif",
      "steal-wheel.gif",
      "this-is-fine.gif",
      "huey-louis.gif",
      "fly-a-plane.gif",
      "van-dancer.gif",
      "arnold-rama.gif",
      "more-hulk.gif",
      "i-must-break-you.gif",
      "military-tank.gif",
      "t1000-2.gif",
      "jurassic-west.gif",
      "coffee-time.gif",
      "air-drop.gif",
      "cool-gif.gif",
      "cool-icegif-2.gif",
      "some-guys-are-doubly-cool.gif",
      "three-amigos.gif",
      "gopher-dance.gif",
      "were-waiting.gif",
      "illegal-kick.gif",
      "the-end-is-near.gif",
      "bat-coffee.gif",
      "scary-beetlejuice.gif",
      "stealth-launch.gif",
      "futurama.gif",
      "spaceballs-fight.gif",
      "spaceballs-suck.gif",
      "pronounce-nucular.gif",

    ],
    getRandom = function(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    },
    animation = ["left", "right"],
    change_image = function() {      
      if (index > 25) {      
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {      
          var j = getRandom(i, images.length);
          var s = images[i];
          images[i] = images[j];
          images[j] = s;      
        }
        index = 0;
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[getRandom(0, images.length)] + ")";      
      }
      var image = images[index++];      
      var anim = animation[getRandom(0, animation.length)];
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('sliding-background');

      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundImage = "url(" + image + ")";
        elements[i].style.animationName = "slide" + anim;
      }
      document.title = image;
      setTimeout(change_image, 10000);
    },
    index = 99;

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    images[i] = path + images[i];
  }
  change_image();

};
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("images/giphy.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 25%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.sliding-background {
  background-image: url("giphy.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slideleft 10s linear infinite
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(100vw - var(--width)));
  }
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc(100vh - var(--width)));
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sliding-background"></div>
</div>
<!--
<h1>LET'S GO!!!</h1>
-->
```